# Equivalent to static fields in IOS

Tags: ios, static-members

I'm more of an Android developer, but i'm beginning to see the light at the end of the tunnel on iOS development.

There is, however, one coding pattern I can't seem to find an equivalent for.

The use of static fields as flags.

Android :

```
public final static int ERROR_EMPTY = 1;
public final static int ERROR_NO_CONNECTION = 2;
public final static int ERROR_WRONG_USER = 4;

...

if (error == MyClass.ERROR_EMPTY) {//do things}
```

What would be the proper way to achieve this on iOS ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Objective-C and C**

i often use prefixes:

```
typedef enum MyClass_Error {
  // never use MyClass_Error_Undefined
  // or you may favor MyClass_Error_None for a valid error code
  MyClass_Error_Undefined = 0,
  MyClass_Error_Empty = 1,
  MyClass_Error_NoConnection = 2,
  MyClass_Error_WrongUser = 4
  // ...
} MyClass_Error;
```

for these value collections. then you get benefits such as typesafety and `switch` value checking.

for non-type constants:

```
enum { MyClass_ConstantName = 4 };
```

and feel free to hide these in the `*.m` when private.

also note that C `enum`s may have gaps in their defined values (unlike Java's).

**Update:** there's an even better way to declare an enum, as demonstrated in Abizern's answer -- if you're sticking with the most recent toolchains. the big reason to use this extension is for binary compatibility and encoding (although i favor fixed-width types for these purposes).

---

There are a few other variations, for the cases when you want to use existing types:

**Private Constant**

MyClass.m

```
static const NSRange MyClass_InputRange = {1,1};
```

**Public Constant**

MyClass.h

```
extern const NSRange MyClass_InputRange;
```

MyClass.m

```
const NSRange MyClass_InputRange = {1,1};
```

---

**Using C++**

You would likely favor introducing a new scope for these values -- either in a class or a namespace, rather than simulating the scope using prefixes.

**Common Mistakes**

- Use of `#define` for constants (unless definition is mandatory when preprocessing)
- Use of short identifiers, and identifiers which are not prefixed
- Use of `static` values in headers
- *Not* using `const` when possible
- Declaring them in the header, when they could be in the `*.m` source.

Comment: Thanks Justin. The first part of your answer is what I was looking for. The update completely lost me. The use of NSRange is really obscur in this context.

Comment: Additional question : You say it is a common mistake not to use const.Can we const an enum ?

Comment: @Yahel the `NSRange` example would not be useful for error codes. however, the example is useful for cases when you want to declare a constant which is a `struct` (cannot be represented as an `enum`).

Comment: @Yahel the enum values (e.g. `MyClass_Error_NoConnection`) are already `const`ant. however, you may find yourself in the situation where you do want a `const` `enum` value -- often when the constant is declared outside of the enum's declaration, such as in a separate header/library. in these cases, you would use the same form  as seen in the following sections: `*extern-or-static* const MyClass_Error SomeName = MyClass_Error_WrongUser;`

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Justin's excellent answer - the Modern Objective-C definition for the enum would be:

```
typedef enum MyClass_Error : NSUInteger {
  // never use MyClass_Error_Undefined
  // or you may favor MyClass_Error_None for a valid error code
  MyClass_Error_Undefined = 0,
  MyClass_Error_Empty = 1,
  MyClass_Error_NoConnection = 2
  // ...
} MyClass_Error;
```

Comment: Can you tell me what benefits that new type adds to the mix ? Is it some kind of type enforcement or does it allow to create enums that contains NsStrings ?